# Fancytree select / deselect node pressing CTRL key

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript, fancytree

Hello I'm using the fancytree library in my project and I wanted to deselect all the nodes by pressing the CTRL key i faced a problem with the last node, cannot be deselected.
Scenarios:

1. In the case of multiselect I can deselect all the nodes except the last one.
2. In the normal case I cannot deselect the active node.

***Is there a way to deselect all nodes? thank you in advance.***

```js
$("#container").fancytree({
 //Other events...
 click: (event, data) => {
  // retrieve clicked node.
  let node = data.node;
  if (event.ctrlKey) {
   if (node) {
    if (node.isSelected()) {
     node.setSelected(false);
    } else {
     node.setSelected(true);
    }
   }
  }
 },
 //Other events...
});
```

I implemented this code but not worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

visit through tree and select all nodes in it .. here's the code

```
    var tree= $.ui.fancytree.getTree("#tree")
    tree.visit(function (node) {
        node.selected=true;
    });
```